# How can I configure this java crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler

I want to configure this java crawler (http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/). But I am confuse how can I do this as this is the first time I am working on this. I have downloaded all those two files that was written in that description (***" One of them contains crawler4j jar file and config files and the other contains dependencies of crawler4j. Put all of these in your classpath."***) but I am confuse how should I put those two files in my classpath.. My classpath contains ( **.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\Java.zip;C:\apps\apache\tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\apps\apache\tomcat7\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\apps\apache\tomcat7\lib\el-api.jar** ).
Any suggestions will be appreciated as I am new to this..

Comment: "Any suggestions .." Put this project aside until the concept of the class-path is not mysterious to you. "..will be appreciated.."  Famous last words.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I know about classpath but how can I add those two things in my classpath.. that's what I want to know..

Answer (score 0):

Add the two directories to the class-path using wildcards.  See [Setting the class path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for details.

Comment: thanks for your response..There are two folders: One is crawler4j and that contains crawler4j-2.6.1 and lib folder and second folder is crawler4j-dependencies-lib
So I should add these things in my classpath:
C:\crawler\crawler4j;C:\crawler\crawler4j-dependencies-lib;C:\crawler\crawler4j\lib;C:\crawler\crawler4j\crawler4j-2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the new crawler4j github:
https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j

Use the maven dependency system and all of your trouble will be gone!:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.uci.ics</groupId>
    <artifactId>crawler4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```